# Wrap labels of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[
pdftex,
12pt,
a4paper,
chapterprefix,
headinclude,
headsepline,
footsepline,
colordvi,
twoside,
halfparskip,
final,
appendixprefix,
pointlessnumbers,
tablecaptionabove,
BCOR=12mm,
DIV=16, 
bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, fit, positioning, chains, arrows.meta}

%%% styles for Figure: Structure of the paper %%%

\begin{document}
\tikzset{arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth,}}
\tikzset{arrow2/.style = {thick,dotted,->,>=stealth,}}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum width=3cm,draw,label=center:Input Scripts] (reg1) at (0,0){};

\node[circle,minimum size=3cm, draw, label=center:Export Files] (c1) at (6,0){};

\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum width=3cm,draw,label=center:Input Files] (reg2) at (12,0){};

\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, minimum width=3cm,draw,label=center:Execute] (s1) at (6,-6){};


\draw[arrow] (reg1.east) -- (c1.west);
\draw[arrow] (c1.east) -- (reg2.west);
\draw[arrow] (reg1.east) -- (s1.north);
\draw[arrow] (reg2.west) -- (s1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[work-flow prepossess-0]{Prepossessing part-0} \label{fig:pre2inout}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I need to wrap the Label of the nodes. `Input \\ scripts`. But it is not working.

```
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum width=3cm,draw,label=center:Input \\ Files] (reg2) at (12,0){};
```

Comment: Could you please explain your problem at the question body.

Comment: Are you going to remove 'Input Scripts'? If yes, remove ',label=center:Input Scripts'.

Comment: I need label but as a wrap text.
"Input. \newline Scripts"

Comment: If you want to put a \\ in a Tikz node, we must give the option `align=left` to that node (see p. 229 of `pgfmanual.pdf`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth,}}
\tikzset{arrow2/.style = {thick,dotted,->,>=stealth,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum width=3cm,draw, text width=1.2cm,align=center] (reg1) at (0,0){Input Scripts};

\node[circle,minimum size=3cm, draw, label=center:Export Files] (c1) at (6,0){};

\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum width=3cm,draw,label=center:Input Files] (reg2) at (12,0){};

\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, minimum width=3cm,draw,label=center:Execute] (s1) at (6,-6){};

\draw[arrow] (reg1.east) -- (c1.west);
\draw[arrow] (c1.east) -- (reg2.west);
\draw[arrow] (reg1.east) -- (s1.north);
\draw[arrow] (reg2.west) -- (s1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]